# Regular expression return only first occurence

Tags: python, regex

I don't understand why my regular expression extraction don't return all occurences (https://regex101.com/r/1yWpq6/1):

```
import re

s = """
_('hello')

foo

_('world')

bar

"""

print(re.search('_\(\'(.*)\'\)', s, re.MULTILINE).groups())
```

produce

> ('hello',)

I expect ``('hello', 'world')

Why only thirst occurence returned ?

Comment: From the docs of `re.search()`: "Scan through string looking for the first location…"

Comment: You may just use `re.findall(r"_\('([^']*)'\)", s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(re.findall('_\(\'(.*)\'\)', s, re.MULTILINE))
```

out:

```
['hello', 'world']
```

> `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>   Scan through string looking for a
>   location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and
>   return **a corresponding match** object.
>
> `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>   Return all non-overlapping
>   matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) like this:

```
print(re.findall('_\(\'(.*)\'\)', s))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> print(re.findall('_\(\'(.*)\'\)', s))
['hello', 'world']
```